# WatchService watching files on distributed filesystem from multiple machines

Tags: java, concurrency, java-11, watchservice

I am trying to implement a WatchService that watches a filesystem for changes. Once files get created I want to create tasks for each new file and add that task to a distributed queue to let it get processed from multiple machines.

My question now is how I get the different watchservices to not add the same task to the queue.
Lets say machine 1 and machine 2 get the ENTRY_CREATE event at the same time and try to add it to the queue. Should I check before each

> queue.offer(task)

wether that task is already present?

> queue.contains(task)

Or is there a better way on the
WatchService side?

Could it be bad if I have to check containsKeys(task) all the time or is this no problem?
Or do you even have better ideas/approaches?

EDIT:
The queue implementation I was going to use (https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.0/data-structures/priority-queue)
provides the necessary synchronization and after reading the WatchService documentation again I also noticed, that the events do not always get processed in the same order. So my problems resolved themselves after reading those documentations again.

Comment: This is known as the “*check-then-act*” anti-pattern. After `queue.contains(task)` returned `false`, nothing guarantees that the queue still doesn’t contain the task by the time of your subsequent `queue.offer(task)` call. Even worse, a queue has two ends. What if the task has been retrieved already? Then, `queue.contains(task)` would return `false` again while the task might be in progress—or even completed. But we can’t tell you a solution to the problem you didn’t describe. We don’t know anything about your distributed queue or why you watch the same filesystem with different machines.

Comment: Okay sorry my bad. With distributed Queue I meant that i am planning to use Hazelcasts PriorityBlockingQueue implementation (https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/data-structures/priority-queue). 

I watch the same filesystem with different machines because this application is gonna be deployed on multiple servers, with an underlying distributed filesystem. And because I dont want to write specific code for each server, I do want a solution that could work out of the box.

Comment: And you’re using Java’s built-in watch service? Is there no specific service for the distributes filesystem? You should [edit] your question and add as much information about your actual use case as possible…

Comment: After writing down the edit and reading more about it I noticed that the problem I was asking was actually solved in the first place. thanks